# IndexError: list index out of range. Trying to create a list of dictionaries for BeatifulSoup items

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup, index-error

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries with data scraped from a website.
The list of data: Price, price per gramm, Brand.

In the first part, where I pull price and price_per_gramm and append data to the list, everything works well.
Now I have a list of dictionaries where the only one field "Brand" is empty.
So I try to replace those empty fields with actual data and meet IndexError.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("./FULL_data.html"), "html.parser")
list_of_sku = []

for divs in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class" : "col-xs-6 col-sm-4"}):
    item = {"Brand": "",
            "price": "",
            "price per gramm": ""}
    links = divs.find_all("tr")
    for row in links:
        # We get list of prices here
        item_text = row.find('td')
        item_text2 = row.find('span', {"class": "text-primary"}).text
        if item_text and item_text2:
            item["price"] = str(item_text.text)
            item["price per gramm"] = str(item_text2)
            list_of_sku.append(item)

    #We get a brand here
    i=0
    for row in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class" : "js-equalized-brand"}):
        list_of_sku[i]["Brand"] = str(row.text)
        print(list_of_sku[i]["Brand"])
        i += 1
    print(list_of_sku)
```

Here is an error:

```
    Original Stash

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/MyFirstOne/WEBSCRAPING/Work with Soup data.py", line 41, in <module>
    list_of_sku[i]["Brand"] = str(row.text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help to find a solution.

Comment: Add `print(list_of_sku)` after `i=0` and add the output to your question (if still need an answer)

Comment: On a second note, check the identation of `i=0` and bellow code; shouldn't be at the same level with `for divs in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class" : "col-xs-6 col-sm-4"})`?

Comment: I added it and only one line showed up. So I doubled a "divs" loop before the "i=0" and everything works now. Thank you!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Will add the suggestion to answers with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different indention levels between `for divs in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class" : "col-xs-6 col-sm-4"}):`

and

```
i=0
for row in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class" : "js-equalized-brand"}):
    list_of_sku[i]["Brand"] = str(row.text)
    print(list_of_sku[i]["Brand"])
    i += 1
print(list_of_sku)
```

thus causing the 2nd loop to 'play' for each `divs`. (and resetting too).